# how to extract data into list of dicts from excel spreadsheet in python?

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd

I am trying to parse an excel spreadsheet using *xlrd* python library.

[image]

Above picture is a sample data from my spreadsheet. I am trying to parse this data like this
`'genders': [{'gender': 'male', 'country': 'USA'}, {'gender': 'female', 'country': 'canada'}]`
but couldnt quite get at it.

I have tried `data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]` but I dont see the data that I am looking for.

Could someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good for reading xls file.
But you want to `serialize` your data. You specified how must output be, this is the procedure of [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) data, so... Here a quick and basic solution.

```py
# Reading an excel file using Python
import xlrd

# Give the location of the file.
loc = ("file.xls")

# To open Workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)

# no comment about sheets, understant that you have only one sheet, set 0 ( first) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

# output is the serialized object
output = {'genders': []}

# we will iterate over rows, skipping first that is header ( 0+1 )
for i in range(0+1, sheet.nrows):
    # As first column is empty, we will assing to _
    _, gender, country = sheet.row_values(i)
    
    # filling serialized object
    output['genders'].append({'gender': gender,
                              'country': country})

print(output)
```

My output:

```
/home/gil/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/bin/python /home/gil/PycharmProjects/testing/soxlrd.py
{'genders': [{'gender': 'caca', 'country': 'bebe'}, {'gender': 'cece', 'country': 'dede'}, {'gender': 'ee', 'country': 'ff'}, {'gender': 'gg', 'country': 'hh'}]}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: to you!! @Robin

Comment: Actually, how do we know how many rows will be there in the table. 
let's say there can be 20 rows or there can be None under a table. Is there a way to detect this?

Comment: Yes, sheet.nrows will tell you. See docs -> https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=sheet.nrows#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.nrows